# Json in swift 3 passing array

Tags: json, swift

```
subject_id=[{"program_id": "1","subject_id":"1"},{"program_id":%20"2","subject_id":"5"}]
```

I Want to make this type of json.

This is my code i am trying to change subject_id only but it prints whole array. how can i change it.

```
let subject_id = [String](arrayLiteral: "1","5")

let program_id = [String](arrayLiteral: "1","3")

for program_id in program_id
        {
            print(program_id)
        }

        let phoneNumbersDictionary = program_id.map({ ["program_id": $0 , "subject_id" : $0 ] })


        let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

        if let JSON1 = JSON
        {
            print(String(data: JSON1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `map`, `zip` the 2 arrays before. Here is the working snippet

`let pNumbers = zip(subject_ids, program_ids).map { s_id, p_id in ["subject_id": s_id, "program_id": p_id] }`

Answer (score 0):

For-in would be easier:

```
var index = 0
for pid in program_id {
    array.append(["program_id": pid, "subject_id": subject_id[index]])
    index = index + 1
}
```

If you really want to use map:

```
let phoneNumbersDictionary = program_id.map({ ["program_id": $0 , "subject_id" : subject_id[program_id.index(of: $0)!]]})
```

But I'd like to avoid the force unwrap.